# Can I reference concatenated columns in another column during the same INSERT?

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert, string-concatenation

I intend to insert a row in table `apartments`, however this row contains a column `full_address` which is a combination of some text with the house number in `apartments.house_no` and the street name in `apartments.house_street` all of which are being inserted simultaneously.  E.g

| House-no | house_street | full_address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Shiba | No 1, Shiba Street |
| 2 | Lancel | No 2, Lancel street |

I successfully concatenated these columns AS `f_address` output i.e from the statement: `SELECT CONCAT('No '||apartments.house_no ||', '||apartments.house_street ||' Street.') AS f_address`
E.g

|  | f_address |
| --- | --- |
|  | No 1, Shiba street |

but inserting this output into the `full_address` column creates an error. I'm currently using postgres 16 with the pgadmin 4.7 client. Thank you experts for your anticipated response.

Comment: You'll need to show us the table schema as SQL, the query you are using for the insert, and the query you are using to fetch the output. Please [edit] your question to include them, we cannot help you otherwise

Comment: Is the column named f_address, full_address, "full address" or "Full address"? all three are mentioned above.... Same for the other columns. Also, please include the error message. Asuming your column naming style is the issue, i included a sollution below based on the table image provided

Comment: 1) Why are you doing this? The "Full Address"  info could be built when the data is extracted. 2) If you want to do this, use [Generated columns](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue is in the diffrent way you handle the column names. They are both "First char capital" and lowercase, and the wordbreaks are handled wit spaces, underscores and scores. These need to be handled when you insert, but double quoting the ones which are a problem:

INPUT:

[image]

QUERY:

```
UPDATE public.apartments
    SET "Full address"= 'No '||"House-no"||', '||house_street||' Street';
```

RESULT:

[image]

My best Guess is you either miss the double quotes on "Full address" to maintain the space or on "House_no" to maintain the capitalized H.
Also make sure you also created the column before you update...

Comment: From your answer. You first created the other columns and later updated the table to fill the "Full address" column with their concatenation. In my attempt, I tried running everything on the first insert. I'll try your approach this time. Thanks

Comment: This method worked perfectly. Grateful for it

Comment: Great to hear. Might be interesting for you to also look into generated columns as mentioned by @adrian klaver in a comment on the original post.